# Could you please help me analyze this sentence? what does it mean

Tags: word-usage, sentence

> Fervor is the weapon of choice of the impotent

I am confused about the "choice of impotent." Does it mean sb is motivated by fervor to choose sth impotent?

Comment: It means those who can't act (i.e., who can do nothing) have only their passion as a weapon.  In other words, they are weaponless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence "of choice" and "of the impotent" both describe "the weapon."

Removing "of choice," we have "fervor is the weapon of the impotent."

"Of choice" describes the weapon simply meaning that it is their favorite, best, or most commonly used weapon. See [of choice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of-choice).

The sentence is stating that "fervor" (excitement and passion) is what "impotent" people commonly use.